# applying progress dialog if the internet connectivity is low in android

Tags: android, progressdialog

How to apply progress dialog if the internet connectivity is low and some response is coming from server side and that is taking some time because of low internet connectivity.  I have applied the progress dialog already but it is being shown for some time and then a black screen appears as the internet connectivity is low some times.
How to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: use asynctask for background operation, then you will get the dialog till the data loads

Answer (score 0):

u should make use of an `Asynctask()` that will run in the background without causing hiccups in the UI thread...

Since android apps run on a single main (UI ) thread, u should avoid doing heavy tasks on the UI thread

An asynctask is basically an intelligent worker thread provided by the android system.. It contains helper methods wherein u can easily decide what u want to do

A progress dialog should be created in `onPreExecute()` and dismissed in `onPostExecute()`
Call your server in `doInBackgound()`

U can follow these tutorials which will help u achieve what u want :

2.[complete tutorial for a better understanding](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/14/handling-progress-dialogs-and-screen-orientation-changes/)

3.[another easy to understand link](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-developmentthreading-part-2-async-tasks/)